# Regex - Match word against sentence

Tags: regex, nspredicate

I'd like to write a regex query to be run on a set of elements.

The query should return an element, as long as the search term matches the start of the word, and that all the words in the search term are in the match string.

For example:

```
Search Term: "hell"
matches: "hello", "oh hello", "oh-hello"
doesn't match: "shell" - doesn't start the word out
```

My first attempt was to use `BEGINSWITH[c]`, however that wouldn't match "oh hello" from above.  So I think I probably need to use `MATCHES[c] %@` and use some sort of regex.  Anybody good with regex to have some ideas?

Comment: try `\b` (word boundary): ie match `\bhell`

Comment: or try `(^hell)|([^a-z]hell)`, but word boundary suggestion from @Bohemian is better

Answer (score 0):

Regex

```
^hell[^ ]+|[^ ]+[ -]hell[^ ]+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below find anywhere that matches a word;

```
\bHell(o|)?\b
```

i don't believe that is the best way as the ...(o|)? is telling Regex to find where it matches Hell and then anywhere that 'Hell' has an o after it.

Hope that helps